# strange php oop behavior, can someone explain?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

In a nutshell: a class inherits a function from its parent. This function then gets called on the child, but appears to still have the scope of the *parent* class. Is this expected behavior?

Consider the following code example:

```
<?php
class OLTest {
    private $var1 = 10;

    public function getVar1() {
        if (isset($this->var1)) {
            return $this->var1;
        } else {
            return 'undefined';
        }
    }

    public function getVar2() {
        if (isset($this->var2)) {
            return $this->var2;
        } else {
            return 'undefined';
        }
    }
}

class OLTest2 extends OLTest {
    private $var1 = 11;
    private $var2 = 20;
}

$oltest = new OLTest();
$oltest2 = new OLTest2();

echo "calling parent->getVar1\n";
echo $oltest->getVar1() . "\n";

echo "calling parent->getVar2\n";
echo $oltest->getVar2() . "\n";

echo "calling child->getVar1\n";
echo $oltest2->getVar1() . "\n";

echo "calling child->getVar2\n";
echo $oltest2->getVar2() . "\n";
?>
```

To my understanding, the output should be:

```
calling parent->getVar1
10
calling parent->getVar2
undefined
calling child->getVar1
11
calling child->getVar2
20
```

The actual output on my machine is:

```
calling parent->getVar1
10
calling parent->getVar2
undefined
calling child->getVar1
10
calling child->getVar2
undefined
```

To add to the confusion, a `print_r($this)` within either of the functions, will show that the scope is really set to the subclass, yet it's impossible to access the variable.

Can someone clear this up for me?

EDIT: I am using PHP in version 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.5.

Comment: forgot about that. its 5.3.3.

Comment: added as simple way to check isset and return value or undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the output should definetly be `10, undefined, 10, undefined`.
The reason is that the variables that are `private` are visible only to the class defining them (not super or subclasses).

So, when `child` is called, its methods are defined in the parent object and when they resolve `var1` or `var2` they check in the scope definied for `OLTest`.
`var2` is not accessible too because the declared `var2` is only visible inside `OLTest2`.

To get your output, your should declare these variables `protected` or `public`.

Comment: alright thanks. seems like i need to freshen up my oop a little :)

Comment: I understand this is an OOP implementation decision from the PHP team - not an absolute OOP rule. Maybe i'm wrong, but that's how I see it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be related to the `private` scope.

Try changing to `protected` or `public` anc check the results.

Comment: changing the variable scope fixes this. but shouldn't the inherited method be executed with the scope of the subclass in the first place?

Comment: It seems the method runs "inside the class" instead of "inside the instance". In this case, "OLTest" (the class) can't see "var2", and can see only its own "var1", even if "$oltest2" (the instance) is an "OLTest2" object...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is because your properties are private. The methods you are calling still belong to parent class as you haven't redefined them. To enable parent methods accessing child's properties you must make them `protected` in both parent and child classes:

```
class OLTest {
    protected $var1 = 10;

    public function getVar1() {
        if (isset($this->var1)) {
            return $this->var1;
        } else {
            return 'undefined';
        }
    }

    public function getVar2() {
        if (isset($this->var2)) {
            return $this->var2;
        } else {
            return 'undefined';
        }
    }
}

class OLTest2 extends OLTest {
    protected $var1 = 11;
    protected $var2 = 20;
}
```

If you keep it `private` in parent class it won't allow child class to override that property, so the function belonging to parent class will be accessing its own private property. And if you make it private in child class it won't allow parent methods to access it.

If you still want to keep them private you'll have to copy-paste code of your methods into child class (yes, `return parent::getVar1()` won't work either).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "inject" `private $var2` into the parent class, which is what you were trying to do.
So yes, that is normal behavior.

Comment: how is it then that when i change the variable scope to protected, it works as expected?

Answer (score 1):

Because you have declared your vars private, they are totally hidden from each other.  Thus the `$var1` in the parent is actually a different variable from the `$var1` in the child

When you call `getVar1` on the parent, it uses the `$var1` it sees, the one from the parent with the value 10.  Similarly the parent cannot see the child's `$var2`, so to it the property is undefined.

When you call `getVar1` and `getVar2` on the child, the methods themselves are inherited from the parent class and behave exactly as they would if they were called from an object of the type OLTest

Answer (score 0):

It's the scope of your private variables, try using protected

```
class OLTest {
    protected $var1 = 10;

    public function getVar1() {
        return isset($this->var1) ? $this->var1:'undefined';
    }

    public function getVar2() {
        return isset($this->var2) ? $this->var2:'undefined';
    }
}

class OLTest2 extends OLTest {
    protected $var1 = 11;
    protected $var2 = 20;
}

$oltest  = new OLTest();
$oltest2 = new OLTest2();

echo "calling parent->getVar1\n".$oltest->getVar1()."\n";
echo "calling parent->getVar2\n".$oltest->getVar2()."\n";
echo "calling child->getVar1\n".$oltest2->getVar1()."\n";
echo "calling child->getVar2\n".$oltest2->getVar2()."\n";
```

Results:

```
calling parent->getVar1
10
calling parent->getVar2
undefined
calling child->getVar1
11
calling child->getVar2
20
```